# ExtJS web display are different in Chrome toggle device mode and mobile browser

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, browser, extjs5

Hi I am tried to build a web application that can be used via mobile browser.

First, I develop the web and simulate the mobile mode via Chrome.

[image]

However, I use the mobile connected to the site, the display is not the same as the Chrome.

[image]

I have no idea to fix this problem. Could anyone give me suggestions or any key words for google?

Thanks

Comment: are you using sencha touch?

Comment: no. my version is extjs 5.0.1

Comment: on which mobile are you testing it? did you try android and iOS and the results was the same?

Comment: I tried on asus zenfone and iphone 6. The result was the same.

Comment: can you please share a fiddle?

Comment: or also a link to try that

Comment: Have you tryed it also with other mobile browsers? or only with chrome?

Comment: resolution of first screen is not the same of device iphone 4, have you changed it manually?

Comment: have you tryed to reload the page on desktop browser after setting the mobile view?

Comment: I have found another discussion [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779172/extjs-apps-on-iphone).

Comment: it seems like the framework problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

In `ext-all.js`, there is a function `initMeta` to set meta.

```
initMeta: function() {
                var me = this,
                    maxScale = me.maxUserScale || 1;

                me.addMeta('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=' +
                       maxScale + ', user-scalable=' + (maxScale !== 1 ? 'yes' : 'no'));
                me.addMeta('apple-mobile-web-app-capable', 'yes');
            },
```

We can modify the `initial-scale` value make it less than 1.

Hope this trick will help others.

**UPDATE**

I think this is a better way to avoid modify ext-all.js.

When app.js execute launch function I add these code:

```
launch: function() {
    if (Ext.supports.Touch) {
        var head = Ext.getHead(),
            viewportMeta = head.dom.getElementsByTagName('meta')[0];

        viewportMeta.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=0.5, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=yes');
    }
}
```